# PhoneApplicationPage navigation question

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, page-lifecycle

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have three pages, P1, P2 and P3.

From P1 I can go to P2, and from P2 I can go to P3.

I want to execute some code only when I go back from P3 to P2.

How can I do that?

And if I want to execute another code only when I go from P1 to P2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `OnNavigatedFrom` method of class `PhoneApplicationPage` and store the current page in a global static variable.

Override `OnNavigatedTo` as well, in there you check the variable and execute your code depending on it's value.  Dont forget to persist the variable when your application gets tombstoned, you can persist it in the `PhoneApplicatiopnPage.State` dictionary

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to to matches how classical finite state automata's do. You only need a variable that will persist beyond your page's life time to accomplish this.

Within App.xaml.cs create a new public string property.

```
public string PreviousPage { get; set; }
```

Within your pages Page_Load method you can check the previous page and act on it.

```
Page_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     switch(App.PreviousPage)
     {
       case "P1":
         //do something
         break;
       case "P2":
         //do something different
         break;
       case "P3":
         //do something fantastic
         break;
       default:
         //I have no idea how we got here. 
         break;
    }
    //After we have done out work let's update PreviousPage
    App.PreviousPage="P1";//or what ever the page name is. 
}
```

Comment: Doing this with Android it's so easy. Android has a OnResume method to do what I want to do.